# Haskell function ["A","B"] [True, False]

Tags: haskell

does anyone know a function can make

```
f ["A","B"] [True, False]
```

to

```
[[("A", True), ("B", True)], [("A", True), ("B", False)], [("A", False), ("B", True)], [("A", False), ("B", False)]]
```

and

```
f ["A","B","C"] [True, False]
```

to

```
[[("A", True), ("B", True), ("C", True)], 

[("A", True), ("B", True),("C",False)], 

[("A", True), ("B", False),("C",True)],

[("A", False), ("B", True),("C",True)],

[("A", False), ("B", False),("C",True)],

[("A", True), ("B", False),("C",False)],

[("A", False), ("B", True),("C",False)],

[("A", False), ("B", False),("C",False)]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this looks like all possible 2-sized combinations from the second list, each zipped with the first list. You have confirmed this in the comments to this answer. (but in the future, please take time to explain exactly what you need; don't keep people guessing)

---

To calculate all possible combinations of the second list, of a certain length, we can use recursion:

```
combinations xs 0 = [[]] 
combinations xs len = [ x:s | x <- xs, s <- combinations xs (len-1) ]
```

The idea is that (1) for length 0, there is just one possible combination, and it's empty, and (2) for combinations of any other length, we first calculate all combinations of the *previous* length (i.e. `len-1`), and then combine each of them with every possible first element.

Let's try this out:

```
> combinations [0,1] 2
[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
```

Now that we have these combinations, all that's left is to `zip` each of them with the first list:

```
f xs ys = [ zip xs comb | comb <- combinations ys (length xs) ]
```

---

**For bonus points**:

This solution is just a tiny bit inefficient, because we have to call `length xs`, which is an O(n) operation for Haskell lists. In practice this is not a big deal, because it will probably be drowned out by calculating all those combinations. But just for academic interest, this could be optimized by using the *first list itself* for counting down instead of the "length" as a number:

```
combinations xs [] = [[]] 
combinations xs (_:tail) = [ x:s | x <- xs, s <- combinations xs tail ]
```

Here, in the base case I have replaced the zero with an empty list, and in the inductive case I have replaced subtracting 1 with deconstructing the list.

This new optimized `combinations` function can then be used at the top level:

```
f xs ys = [ zip xs comb | comb <- combinations ys xs ]
```

**And finally**, most people would probably prefer `fmap` to list comprehension in this case:

```
f xs ys = zip xs <$> combinations ys xs
```

Comment: But what I got is [("A",True),("B",True),("A",False),("B",False)]

Comment: Yeah, that is what I mean, which is like a matrix.

Comment: I still have confusion about what is the function subsets means. Could you explain about it?